# jquery elastic textarea issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using this plugin :`http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/` and this is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#<%=Message_txt.ClientID %>").elastic();
   var keyPressCount = 0;
        $(window).keyup(function (e) {
            if (keyPressCount++ % 10 == 0) {
                chat.server.onuserTyping(ToClient, fromClient);
            }
            var enterkey = e.which == 13 || e.KeyCode == 13 || e.charCode == 13 ? true : false;
            if (enterkey) {
                var Msgtxt = $("#<%=Message_txt.ClientID %>").val().trim();
                if (Msgtxt == null) return false;
                $("#<%=Send_btn.ClientID %>").trigger("click");

            }
        });
     });
```

as you can see when the enter key is pressed i am triggering the send_btn click the problem is after the button is triggered the textarea loose the elastic functionality and i don't know why

Comment: Why not just? `var enterkey = e.which == 13 || e.KeyCode == 13 || e.charCode == 13` :)

Comment: but what do you mean that is not my question the send_btn click is working so fine but the textarea is loosing the elastic functionality